# R using RODBC in 64bit mode to connect with 32bit MS Access 2010

Tags: r, odbc

I love the RODBC package, but unfortunately my work only has Office 2010 32Bit installed.  This is starting to be an issue since the primary reason I'm using R is to work with giant datasets, which demand 64bit mode.

I already know that 64bit R won't make a 32bit ODBC connection... but is there a way around this?

One hack I can think of is creating a 32bit script that will grab the data generated in the 64bit session and do the database work.  But that would require a few data handshakes.

Most elegant would be to somehow, temporarily, trick R into 32bit so it can throw the data into the database, then be back in 64 bit afterwards.

Is that possible?

Comment: I believe you will have to use an ODBC-ODBC bridge to do this, e.g., http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01026.html

Comment: Yikes, I'm hoping I don't need to ask my boss for 1100 pounds, not even sure what that would be in dollars.

Comment: I found another one here, maybe it's cheaper: http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/